# How do I control parameter sniffing and/or query hints in entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, query-hints, parameter-sniffing

Update: I've created a suggestion to implement hint control in a future version of EF. [Go here to vote for it.](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2718461-provide-a-way-to-control-parameter-sniffing-and-or)

I have a problem where one of my Entity Framework (EF) queries is taking a very long time to execute in Sql Server, although when I copy-and-paste the generated TSQL into Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) it runs extremely fast. After some investigation I found that I was experiencing a parameter sniffing issue, and the [correct way to fix it](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) is to insert one of many query hints (OPTIMIZE FOR, RECOMPILE, and so on). How do I insert these hints into my EF queries?

Related questions coming at this from different perspectives are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270490/entity-framework-4-2-exec-sp-executesql-does-not-use-indexes-parameter-sniffing), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158102/force-hint-to-index-from-entity-framework-to-sql-server), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141104/using-nolock-hint-in-ef4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a hint on a query generate by EF, you should use plan guides, more info here: [One to one join Not fast enough in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062501/one-to-one-join-not-fast-enough-in-sql-server)

Comment: Does anybody have an actual EF example of this?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario? I faced this issue a long time ago and the final solution was around it, not through.

Comment: I came up with a different solution based on interceptors which are, I believe, a newer feature in EF (probably didn't exist at the time of your answer). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761827/adding-a-query-hint-when-calling-tvf

Answer (score 2):

If you are executing stored procedures you could declare the parameters of the stored procedure internally.

I.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
(
     @param1     NVARCHAR(10),
     @param2     INT
)

AS

DECLARE @internalParam1 NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @internalParam2 INT

SET @internalParam1 = @param1
SET @internalParam2 = @param2

-- REST OF YOUR QUERY

GO
```

This will stop SQL Server caching any parameters that are being passed to the SP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I'm looking for a way to add hints into the query that EF generates, not a stored procedure.

Comment: I've had a quick google and there is nothing obvious for your problem with EF, other ORMS such as NHibernate allow query hints.  These posts below are the closest solution I can find to your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031069/how-can-i-specify-an-index-hint-in-entity-framework

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926656/entity-framework-with-nolock